# How to run a Windows executable (exe) from WSL with root privileges?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, root, wsl2, neovim

The title might not be totally accurate, as my goal is to launch an `.exe` from a WSL2 shell which itself starts a *Linux process* inside WSL, and I want said Linux process to be ran *as root*

**Goal**: Use a Neovide (Neovim GUI that [in my case] runs on a Linux instance of Neovim installed in WSL2) Neovim buffer with root-level privileges.

**Issue**: running `sudo neovide.exe --wsl filename.foo` from inside a WSL shell opens a non-root Neovim instance with regular user write permissions.